# Convergence of a sequence defined recursively

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_0 = 2, a_1 = 3$ and consider the sequence defined recursively by
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_na_{n-1}}$$

We have to show it converges and we have to find the limit. My approach was to show(as suggested by my professor) to show that the odd subsequence and the even subsequence converge to the same limits. However I'm not able to do that(using the basic properties of convergent sequences). Hints and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should it be $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n a_{n-1}}$$

Comment: duly noted and edited

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Write out the first couple terms and note the powers of $a_0,a_1$ involved. You will see they follow a basic arithmetic recurrence you can more easily solve.

E.g.,
$$a_0, a_1, a_0^{1/2}a_1^{1/2}, a_0^{1/4}a_1^{3/4}, a_0^{3/8}a_1^{5/8}, \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $a_n>0$. Then we get two new patterns
$$
A_{n+1}:=a_{n+1}\sqrt{a_n}=a_n\sqrt{a_{n-1}}=A_{n},\\
B_{n+1}:=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left[\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\right]^{-1/2}=B_{n}^{-1/2}.
$$

Then we get
$$
A_n\equiv3\sqrt{2},\\
B_n=\left[\frac{3}{2}\right]^{(-1/2)^{n-1}},
$$
that is, for $n>0$,
$$
a_n=\sqrt[3]{A_n^2B_n}=\sqrt[3]{18\left[\frac{3}{2}\right]^{(-1/2)^{n-1}}}\to\sqrt[3]{18},\quad n\to\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Consider $b_n = \log_2 a_n \Rightarrow b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(b_n + b_{n-1})$.
- $\Rightarrow 2b_{n+1} - b_n - b_{n-1} = 0$ is a 2nd order linear difference equation with the characteristic polynomial $2x^2-x-1 = 0$
- $2x^2-x-1 = 0$ has the solutions $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$
- $\Rightarrow b_n = c_1\lambda_1^n + c_2\lambda_2^n = c_1 + c_2\left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^n \Rightarrow b_n \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} c_1$
- $b_0 = \log_2 2 = 1$ and $b_1 = \log_2 3 \Rightarrow c_1 = \frac{1}{3}\log_2 18$

$$\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 2^{c_1} = \sqrt[3]{18}}$$